# Bootstrap modal does not appear

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I can't get my Bootstrap modal to display after clicking a button.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- I copied the code from the modal documentation page.
- I have omitted the "hide" class and removed display: none from my styling.

```js
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))

var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function(tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})

var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))

var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function(popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
})

var popover = new bootstrap.Popover(document.querySelector('.example-popover'), {
  container: 'body'
})

var popover = new bootstrap.Popover(document.querySelector('.popover-dismiss'), {
  trigger: 'focus'
})
```

```html
<!-- Button -->
<button id="upcomingCancel1" class="btn btn-danger my-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#upcomingModal1">
    <i class="bi bi-x me-1"></i>Cancel
</button>

<!-- Modal-->
<div id="upcomingModal1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="upcomingModalHeader1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="dialog-content" role="document">

    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="upcomingModalHeader1">Cancel delivery</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="bi bi-x me-1"></i></span>
                    </button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      Do you want to cancel?
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No
                    </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yes
                    </button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kQtW33rZJAHjgefvhyyzcGF3C5TFyBQBA13V1RKPf4uH+bwyzQxZ6CmMZHmNBEfJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.startbootstrap.com/sb-forms-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using BS 4 or 5? You tagged your question with 4, but your code shows 5. Also, did you check your dev tools for errors?

Comment: I'm using BS5, I'll change the tag accordingly. I have a few errors: 
1. Warning: Loading failed for the <script> with source “file:///jquery-1.11.3.min.js”.
2. Error: Uncaught TypeError: this._element is undefined
3. Uncaught Error: GET_ELEMENTS:  -> form[data-sb-form-api-token]

Comment: share your script.js file? What is happening on when button is triggered, that script? If you are or want to do it with JS. Do you want to do it via JS?

Comment: I've edited my post to show the script.js file. I've made a basic modal with JS and it worked, but I wanted to use the Bootstrap version because it looked better.

Comment: I put your code in a snippet so we can work with it. I'm not sure why it's erroring. Are you really using that ancient version of jQuery?

Comment: Oh, I'll change that as well. Copied that from another StackOverflow question.